# Application not open main activity when it is killed after pressing home button in android

Tags: android, android-activity

In my application activity A calls activity B. In activity B I press home button. and after sometime application is killed. But when I open my app again it opens B instead of activity A even though application is killed before.

Comment: How do you know taht the application is killed?

Comment: When you press Home button from your app only your application task comes in background it only killed if os want more memory for new task..

Answer (score 1):

Normally when you press home button your current activity is not killed by os. To solve you problem place this

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

in manifest file in your Activity B tag. Your activity won't be remembered and when you run your application next time, it will bring you to Activity A

Comment: But I want to open main activity only when application killed after pressing home button, not want to always open main activity. Then what to do?

Comment: As far as I know about application life cycle, suppose Activity A is launcher activity from A it called B and from B it called C, In C when I press home button, and again open my app it open C, that is fine in my case. but after pressing home button in C, when it idle for some time and application is killed, after that when I open my app it opens C instead of launcher activity A. Please give me solution what is wrong here.

Comment: @MihirShah I have the same problem.. have you found a solution for this?